# Pasar cadenas codificadas base64 en URL - JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy mandando a través de una URL un String con el valor de un pdf en formato base64.

```
String docBase64 = "mERjpFFjivFVbdVqbWx9tbEWSKL4qMYarbY+qk2rra3V1lrbGqtttVED/M7M3IEF E5t+X7//v/2+ncm558zMmTNzzsycmbm7ZBFGCEXDQ4FaSuor1vyps9CDNJpMhOIP";
String web = "http://localhost:7001/pruebaDoc?datosPdf="+ docBase64;

    URL url = new URL(web);
    
    try {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Y despues yo entro sitio recupero ese valor:

```
 public void recuperaPDF(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    
    System.out.println(req.getParameter("datosPdf"));

    //Aqui me lo devuelve diferente
 }
```

Estoy recuperado un pdf en base64 correctamente, pero al enviarlo por url desde java me quita los caracteres "+", "=" y no me monta bien el pdf.

¿Habría alguna manera de solucionar esto?

[image: A la derecha esta lo que recibo yo, sin los "+"]
A la derecha esta lo que recibo yo, sin los "+"

Comment: Cuando preguntáis algo, lo correcto es adjuntar el código relativo a la pregunta. En este caso, *me imagino* (**Y digo me imagino PORQUE NO VEO EL CÓDIGO!!**) que estás usando la configuración por defecto del encoder por defecto? Como verás, este comentario es más presuponer que responder... hazte un favor y pon el código que necesitamos para poder ayudarte. Aparte de que hay múltiples maneras de obtener un Base64 en java, y no todos funcionan igual ni piden los mismos parámetros...

Comment: @Benito-B acabo de actualizar la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Problemas que veo en la forma de enviar el fichero que estás usando:

- Dependiendo del servidor que reciba la petición, las URL tienen una longitud máxima. Mandar datos como parámetros en una petición es una mala idea si los datos son grandes.

Estás enviando un fichero PDF, ¿no tendría más sentido usar una petición POST y mandar el fichero como parte del cuerpo del mensaje?

Si usas una URL para mandar datos, tienes que saber que la codificación de URL usa ciertos caracteres para delimitar los datos, por lo que si quieres enviarlos como parte de los datos tienes que "escaparlos".
Por ejemplo, con Javascript:

```js
const datoOriginal="Quiero enviar este texto: a + b = c";
console.log(datoOriginal);
console.log(encodeURIComponent(datoOriginal));
```

Como puedes ver se han sustituido:

- espacios por %20
- dos puntos por %3A
- el + por %2B
- el = por %3D

Necesitarías usar algo como:

```java
private static String encodeValue(String value) throws RuntimeException {
    return URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
}
```